# How to add Widgets from outside class with Kivy

Tags: python, class, kivy, kivy-language

Hy! I have this app here, a kind of "To Do List". When I press "Add Item" Button, it opens a PopUp Window and I want when "Up" Button is pressed to add "ItemTemplate" in "ItemsList". I am new in Kivy and I tried do that in last few days. How can I do that?
Thanks a lot!

Python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup

class FirstBox(BoxLayout):
    def btn(self):
        Pu().open()

class ItemsList(GridLayout):
    pass

class ItemTemplate(BoxLayout):
    pass

class Pu(Popup):
    pass

class MyAppApp(App):
    pass

MyAppApp().run()
```

Kv code:

```
FirstBox:
<FirstBox>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    BoxLayout:
        ScrollView:
            ItemsList:
                size_hint: 1, None
                height: self.minimum_height

    Button:
        size_hint: 1,0.2
        text: "Add Item"
        on_release: root.btn()
<ItemsList>:
    cols: 1
    size_hint_y: None
    ItemTemplate:
    ItemTemplate:
    ItemTemplate:
<ItemTemplate>:
    size_hint: 1, None
    CheckBox:
        size_hint: 0.15, 1
    Button:
        text: "Task Name"
    Button:
        text: "Some action"
        size_hint: 0.15,1
<Pu>:
    size_hint: 1, 0.3
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        TextInput:
        Button:
            text: "Up"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give id to your `ItemList` for add widget and `TextInput` for get text from.

```
ItemsList:
    id: viewlist
```

and

```
TextInput:
    id: new_task_input_id
```

Use `StringProperty` for dinamicly change text of ItemTemplate:

```
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
class ItemTemplate(BoxLayout):
    task_text = StringProperty()
```

Edit .kv side dinamic: ( ***ItemTemplate's Button*** )

```
Button:
    text: root.task_text
```

Trigger **Up Button** in .kv side: `on_release: root.add_item()`
Create this function in Pu class and add this operations:

```
def add_item(self,*args):
    firstbox = App.get_running_app().root #access correctly main layout
    itemlist = firstbox.ids.viewlist #find viewlist by id
    new_task_text = self.ids.new_task_input_id.text  #get textinput text
    item = ItemTemplate()  #create custom item
    item.task_text = new_task_text  #set item text
    itemlist.add_widget(item) #add item to layout
```

Short function:

```
App.get_running_app().root.ids.viewlist.add_widget(ItemTemplate(task_text=self.ids.new_task_input_id.text))
```

Lets close popup after add new item:

```
self.dismiss()
```

Also if you want to add this widget to top, need to give index in `add_widget` :

```
itemlist.add_widget(item,len(itemlist.children))
```